# S3 - unable to make public for certain folder using Root account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using my root user account.

In my bucket, there are several folders.
I want to make one of my folder open to public.

When I click `Make public` for the folder, it shows `Failed to edit public access`.

```
Insufficient permissions
You need s3:PutObjectAcl permissions to perform this action. Learn more about
```

I don't understand why it happens because I am using Root account.

My bucket settings:
[image]
[image]
[image]

How to do to make all objects in the bucket are private?

Comment: You already asked this before and I answered in the comments. What's wrong with my answer that you made new question?

Comment: @Marcin because there is new error and different situation. appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The **Make Public** option does not apply to folders. In fact, folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3. For example, you can upload a file to a non-existent folder and the folder will magically 'appear'! (Then, if you delete the object, the folder will magically disappear.)

To make particular folder(s) public:

- In **Block Public Access**, turn off the two options that mention Bucket Policies
- Add a **Bucket Policy** to the bucket, like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/folder1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/folder2/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy is saying: "Allow anyone to GetObject from these folders."